# Qml QColor Type Error

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to set a QColor property of a custom QQuickPaintedItem by passing a QColor from C++ to QML. I have tried the following:

1. Converting QColor to QVariant. In the JS debugger, the color object was empty.
2. Converting QColor to a color string "#RRGGBB". This still throws the type error.

QML Code:

```
    m_DisplayScreens[m_DisplayScreens.length].backgroundColor = m_Model.getBackgroundColor(i_Timer);
```

m_DisplayScreens is a list of my custom QML widget. I can set the backgroundColor property just fine by doing something like.

```
DisplayScreen
{
    backgroundColor: "Red"
}
```

The "m_Model" object is simply a QObject which is the 'backend' of the QML form. The code for getBackgroundColor is as follows:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QString getBackgroundColor(int index);    
QString CountDownPanelModel::getSegmentColor(int index)
{
    return "#003300";
}
```

The specific error is: xxx.js:19: TypeError: Type error

Any help would be appreciated. I've been banging my head against this for a few hours now.

Thanks,

Jec

**1st Edit:**

Ok folks, here is my attempt when returning a QColor;

```
class CountDownPanelModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CountDownPanelModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~CountDownPanelModel() = default;

    Q_INVOKABLE QColor getBackgroundColor(int index);
    Q_INVOKABLE QColor getSegmentColor(int index);
};




QColor CountDownPanelModel::getBackgroundColor(int index)
{
    return QColor(44, 44, 44);
    //return m_TimerList->at(index)->getTimerData()->getBackgroundColor();
}


QColor CountDownPanelModel::getSegmentColor(int index)
{
    return QColor(200, 200, 200);
    //return m_TimerList->at(index)->getTimerData()->getSegmentColor();
}
```

The result of using a QColor is the same as using the QString. I get "Type Error" at the line I assign the color at. For example:

```
var m_DisplayScreens = [];

function createDisplays()
{
    m_DisplayScreens = [];
    var timerCount = m_Model.getTimerCount();
    var bg  = m_Model.getBackgroundColor(0);
    var fg = m_Model.getSegmentColor(0)
    for (var i_Timer = 0;
         i_Timer < timerCount;
         ++i_Timer)
    {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("DynamicSevenSegmentDisplay.qml");
        var display = component.createObject(m_Panel);
        display.initialize(m_Model.getSevenSegmentDisplayInitializer())
        display.y = 100 * (i_Timer);
        m_DisplayScreens[m_DisplayScreens.length] = display;
        m_DisplayScreens[m_DisplayScreens.length].backgroundColor = m_Model.getBackgroundColor(i_Timer);
        m_DisplayScreens[m_DisplayScreens.length].segmentColor = m_Model.getSegmentColor(i_Timer)
    }
    m_Panel.height = 100 * timerCount;

}
```

Just for completeness, here is DynamicSevenSegmentDisplay.qml

```
SevenSegmentDisplayScreen
{
    y: 0
    height: 100
    width: parent.width - x

    backgroundColor: "Black"
    borderPercentage: 10
    displayCount: 20
    text: "1234567890"
    anchors.left: m_SettingsButton.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 8
}
```

I'm completely confused as to why I can't assignthe QColor to backgroundColor. The debugger just shows nothing in the 'value' column. I take it this is the JS version of 'null'.

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of getBackgroundColor?

Comment: from Qt documentation: _When integrating with C++, note that any QColor value passed into QML from C++ is automatically converted into a color value, and vice-versa_
So you have to return QColor from `getBackgroundColor`, not QString

Comment: I had tried a QColor previously. When I tried that approach, the JS debugger showed the object was empty and I still got the Type Error. This just happened to be my latest attempt. I was trying strings since I know you can use a string to set the color. for example color: "#003300" is legal syntax within QML. I just wasn't sure if that work around would work when passing it from C++.

Comment: I will attempt the QColor approach again. I'll upload my results when I get home.

Comment: Are you sure getBackgroundColor returns "#003300"?  From the code you've provided, there's no way for us to tell.

Comment: I am, I stepped through it with the debugger. Somehow though in JS the value is just blank. I'm assumming the fundamental error is that a color can't be assigned (null), which makes since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a definitive answer but I found several issues. I was previously developing using Linux Mint. I recently switched to Ubuntu and found several issues with passing data between C++ and QML. I got a message about a CRC miss match.

"the debug information found in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so" does not match "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so" (CRC mismatch)."

So this also could be part of the problem. But for the most part it looks like its my development machine.